# How to specify field data type when reading from a SQL database

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a SQL table called "Customers".  In it is a CustomerNumber field with values like "0001234567", i.e. they are made up of numbers only, but some include leading 0s.  So, when I try to run something like

```
sqlFetch(channel=myconn, sqtable="Customers", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

it returns my customers table where the CustomerNumber field is numeric (instead of character), and consequently I lose all those leading 0s.

Is there a way I can specify the fieldtype for a column or an alternative solution that won't truncate all my leading 0s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the types of columns more fully using the `as.is` argument, which is documented in the Details section of `?sqlFetch` as well as at the linked documentation for `?sqlQuery` and `?sqlGetResults`.

Basically, it is either a vector of logicals or a vector of numeric or character indices specifying which columns to leave untouched. This vector will be recycled as necessary.

(Note that RODBC will clobber columns stored in the database with `type.convert` *even if the C API correctly returns char or varchar* as the data type of the column in the database. The maintainer has not responded to any of my 4-5 emails on this issue over the past year, and I have since simply used a forked version of RODBC with the needed [one line modification](https://github.com/joranE/RODBC/blob/master/R/sql.R#L641) ever since.)

Comment: 4-5 emails?  I think I'd've given up after the 2nd one ;)

Comment: @Ben Well, around half were to r-sig-db, the other half to the maintainer specifically. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try specifying a query string and you could even cast the field if you're still having problems.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myConn As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("ConnStr")
    Dim sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(myConn)

    Dim strSQL As String = "select cast(CustomerNumber as varchar(30)) as CustomerNumber_varchar, * from Customers"
    Dim myds As DataSet

    sqlConnection.Open()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60

    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    myds = ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(myReader)
    myReader.Close()
End Sub


Public Function ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(ByVal reader As SqlDataReader) As DataSet
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim schemaTable As DataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable()
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    For intCounter = 0 To schemaTable.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dataRow As DataRow = schemaTable.Rows(intCounter)
        Dim columnName As String = CType(dataRow("ColumnName"), String)
        Dim column As DataColumn = New DataColumn(columnName, _
            CType(dataRow("DataType"), Type))
        dataTable.Columns.Add(column)
    Next
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
    While reader.Read()
        Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
        For intCounter = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            dataRow(intCounter) = reader.GetValue(intCounter)
        Next
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
    End While
    Return dataSet
End Function
```

Comment: Wrong language, I think.

Comment: Wrong language for sure.