# R How to avoid conversion to logical when character column contains only null values

Tags: r

I am doing simple query like this:

```
df <- sqlQuery(connectionString, "SELECT myID, CharacterCol1, CharacterCol2, NumericCol3 FROM myTable WHERE myCondition")
```

When database column (e.i. `CharacterCol1` which is oryginaly of `varchar` type) contains only `NULL` values, the query returns `NA` in all records for this column and in resulting `df` the column becomes `logical`.

Is there a way to avoid this conversions? I mean if I can enforce desired column type in `df` even if it contains only `NULL`s?

Comment: `df$your_NA_column <- as.character(df$your_NA_column)`?

Comment: This is coversion after query. It works but I want to avoid convestion because my query has a lot of columns of different types so it generates additional work and is source of possible errors.

Comment: After query, you can convert all logical columns in `df` with `df <- dplyr::mutate_if(df, is.logical, as.character)`, else this question may help with the query itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229590/how-to-specify-field-data-type-when-reading-from-a-sql-database

Comment: I would also suggest explicitly setting the column types of your data.frame. If you want the code to guess the column type and don't give it any information to guess from, you are in for a bumpy ride. The best way would be to get the column types from the database table itself (a bit more code, but would give you a robust and portable solution).

Comment: @jpsmith convertion after query is problematic because I have to know the original type. It is not always `character` but also `numeric`. Both are converted to `logical` if all records are null.

Comment: The best I did till now and works looks like :
`dt <- data.table(myID = integer(), CharacterCol1 = character (), CharacterCol2 = character (), numericCol3 = numeric)

dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, df), fill = TRUE)`
Where `df` is my query result.